# SageMath: defining an extension of a Finite Field

Tags: finite-fields, sagemath

I am trying to do basic 101 manipulation with SageMath

```
F = GF(3); F
```

> Finite Field of size 3

```
R.<x> = F[] ; R
```

> Univariate Polynomial Ring in x over Finite Field of size 3

```
F2 = F.extension(x^2+1,'u');F2
```

> Finite Field in u of size 3^2

```
for i,x in enumerate(F2):  print("{} {}".format(i, x))

0 0 
1 u + 2 
2 u 
3 2*u + 2 
4 2 
5 2*u + 1 
6 2*u 
7 u + 1 
8 1
```

Now i would just like to do simple arithmetic and check for example that $u^2+1 = 0$
But i get an error. I cannot find the right syntax.

```
u^2+1
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 u**Integer(2)+Integer(1)
>
> NameError: name 'u' is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try naming the variable $u$ by using .<u> in your definition of F2, like this.

```
F2.<u> = F.extension(x^2+1)
```

If you don't care what the minimal polynomial of your primitive element of $\mathbb F_9$ is, you could also do this.

```
F2.<u> = GF(3^2)
```

Comment: thanks it does the job

Comment: I am getting error message for this line. F=GF(3);
F2.<u>=F.extension(x^2+1) ; F2
Error::UnboundLocalError: local variable 'E' referenced before assignment; how to over come this  error?