# sagemath GF(p^n) calculations

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, primitive-roots, sagemath

Is there a way to generate the primitive elements in $GF(p^n)$, in say Sagemath, and perform operations with these elements?

For example, using the irreducible polynomial $p(x)=1+x+x^3$ in $GF(2^3)$, how can i generate these primitive elements and how would I go about adding/multiplying them?

I have looked at the online manual, but can't seem to find what I am looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: Sagemath has the `.gen()` and `.multiplicative_generator()` methods which return a single primitive element. I don't think it has a simple command to get all the primitive elements of a Galois field.

Comment: FWIW, a comment to [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1624875/207316) (to a question on mutually orthogonal latin squares) links to a Sage script that produces MOLS using finite field arithmetic. That script is rather terse, but you might find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you.  Perhaps I should try looking at Octave or GAP.  Manually generating these tables, and doing arithmetic is an absolute pain.  I will take a look at that script also.

Comment: I think you want to extend $GF(2)$ with your polynomial.  Does this [question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726681/sagemath-defining-an-extension-of-a-finite-field) help you?

Comment: It looks like the Frobenius companion matrix solves the issue.  Creating a companion matrix of the irreducible polynomial allows me to add and multiply the elements in GF(2^n) with ease.  I suspect it will hold for GF(p^n) - need to confirm still.  Thanks again.